# set custom icon on mail item using office.js

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have to set an custom icon on the mail item on windows outlook I tried to set it via EWS, REST URL and adding extended property as well but nothing works, can someone please help me with that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code samples? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Where exactly do you want to set an icon in Outlook? Is it a folder view?